# Modbus TCP Slave. Data transmit

Tags: c#, datagridview, modbus

I develop c# windows form ModbusTCP Slave application which provides data from dataGridView. 
I create method which reading data from dataGridView and start listen. 
I need that I can refresh data in current listening.

My method:

```
void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse(tbIP.Text);
         int port = Convert.ToInt32(tbPort.Text);
         slaveTcpListener = new TcpListener(address, port);
         slave = ModbusTcpSlave.CreateTcp(1, slaveTcpListener);
         DataStore data = new DataStore();
           for (int i=0; i<dgV.Rows.Count-1; i++)
            { 
            slave.DataStore.InputRegisters[Convert.ToInt32(dgV[0,i].Value)] = (ushort)Convert.ToUInt16(dgV[1,i].Value);
            } 

           slave.Listen();}
```

I need refresh data in DataGridView. How I can it? 
So, if I change data in table and click button again then I get an error.
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `timer` object (more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). For example you can start your timer pressing a button and then the timer can read data and update your gridview.

As an example you can follow these steps:

1. Drag timer object from your Toolbox on your form (it should be in the "*All Windows Forms*" folder). Visual studio should create an object called `timer1` in the lower part of designer window
2. Double click on `timer1`. Visual Studio creates an handler for click event of your timer (it should be called `timer1_Tick()`). The timer will periodically run the code you put in `timer1_Tick()` event handler.
3. Copy the code you wrote for your button in `timer1_Tick()`

   ```
   private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse(tbIP.Text);
       int port = Convert.ToInt32(tbPort.Text);
       slaveTcpListener = new TcpListener(address, port);
       slave = ModbusTcpSlave.CreateTcp(1, slaveTcpListener);
       DataStore data = new DataStore();
       for (int i=0; i<dgV.Rows.Count-1; i++)
       { 
           slave.DataStore.InputRegisters[Convert.ToInt32(dgV[0,i].Value)] = (ushort)Convert.ToUInt16(dgV[1,i].Value);
       } 
       slave.Listen();
   }
   ```
4. Finally you have to configure and start your timer, for example with a button:

   ```
   void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           timer1.Interval = 10000; //timer tick occurs every 10'000ms=10sec
           timer1.Enabled = true;
           timer1.Start(); 
       }
   ```

Now if you click `Button1` your timer starts and should read data from Modbus and update yor `GridView` every 10 seconds.